# Update Table with Case stmt

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a fun side project I have been working on. I added a column for weight (op1w to op12w) to go with the description (op_1 to op_12). Now I need to go back through and update all entries with the appropriate op1w to op12w depending on the op_1 to op_12. Here is a part of the drop_log table with those columns.

[image]

Here are the values to match and what to update the op1w to op12w with (this exists as a table called mechs in the db):

```
mech    weight
AS7 100
AWS 80
BJ  45
BLR 85
CDA 40
CN9 50
COM 25
CPL 65
CTF 70
DISC    0
DRG 60
GRF 55
HBK 50
HGN 90
JM6 65
JR7 35
KTO 55
LCT 20
ON1 75
QKD 60
RVN 35
SDR 30
SHD 55
STK 85
TBT 50
TDR 65
VTR 80
WVR 55
```

Would you guys help me with the case statement for this? I believe it should start something like this:

```
UPDATE drop_log
SET
op1w =(case when some_case_condition then something else op1w end),
op2w =(case when some_case_condition then something else op2w end)
.
```

Thanks for your help.

edit: OK after reading the comments, here is my attept

```
UPDATE drop_log
SET op1w= 
CASE 
    WHEN op_1 = 'AS7'
      THEN op1w = 100
    WHEN op_1 = 'AWS'
      THEN op1w = 80
    .
    .
    .
    ELSE op_1
    END
CASE
    WHEN op_12 = etc
     THEN op12w = etc
    .
    .
    .
    ELSE op_12
END
```

Ok now I see what you guys are saying.. No I don't want you to fill it our for me. This is going to go on and on for each column 1-12 and then each column gets its own case for each weight possibility. Is that all there is to it? I thought it would be more involved.

Comment: and have you tried to implement your solution, or are you just trying to make otherst try it for you? please, try your solution, and if you have any problem, come back with a precise description of the problem

Comment: It seems like you have all of the ideas right and the query "building blocks" right. You just have to test around with the queries and you'll definitely find the right answer.

Comment: I have no idea what to put in the some_case_condition part. Would it be: op1w =(case when op_1 = 'AWS' then op1w= 80 else op1w end),

Comment: I hoped someone could tell me the structure I would need to use for my case stmts to check all those possible weights. Then I would fiddle with it till it worked..

Comment: Did you design this table? If yes, learn normalization.

Comment: No I did not write the table. But thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general format of your query should be:

```
UPDATE drop_log
SET op1w = CASE
            WHEN op_1 = 'AWS' THEN '1'
            WHEN op_2 = 'ABC' THEN op1
            ELSE '0'
          END,
    op2w = CASE
            WHEN op_1 = 'HDP' THEN op_1
            ELSE '0'
          END
```